# Apply single trigger to same tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

Can I apply a single trigger to some tables?

Comment: Depends on what your trigger needs to do. Do you mean that the same trigger should be fired when a DML event, such as insert, happens on any of these tables? Or do you mean that the same trigger, when fired, can manipulate multiple tables?

Answer (score 3):

Triggers are **per-table** - you cannot share them.

If you need triggers on five tables - you need to create five triggers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have functionality to share between triggers, then you can build a stored procedure and call it from the triggers that you have to build per each table.

Comment: You won't be able to access `inserted` and `deleted` from there though.

Comment: That is in fact one of the reasons for which you cannot share the triggers (because the tables are likely to have a different form). But you can make the sp in such way so that you can pass useful information to them.